# Why is there no reference to my own code in this error log? What can I do to avoid something like that?

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-emulator

I tested my application on API 29, everything worked fine.
I now tried to run it on API 27, and it crashed before even loading my launcher activity. The following exception is thrown. Normally I would now have a look at the log, but it doesn't contain any reference to my own code, so I really don't know what could have triggered it. Furthermore, my launcher activity doesn't even contain a bitmap nor draws a canvas. Any ideas?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(441000000bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting that's causing the crash is

```
trying to draw too large(441000000bytes) bitmap
```

that's ~441MB. If you look down the stacktrace a bit, you can see

```
at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
```

so that's in an `ImageView` somewhere. Bitmaps aren't compressed, it's just `width * height * bit depth` so it's probably a large image in terms of dimensions. You should use one that's sized appropriately for how it's displayed.

It's not showing any of your code because this is just the Android framework updating the UI, you can see from the method names that it's drawing all the views it needs to, so your code isn't involved at this point (unless you have a custom view in there).